# overlay a color layer in an image with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a transparent red overlay to an image whenever the image has a `tinted-image` class, I want to do it with CSS. Actually, I want to apply it directly `img` tag. Is this possible?

[My JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/406kmz4c/#&togetherjs=yA7fEiKT5M)

I tried this:

```
<img class="tinted-image" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg"></img>
```

And CSS:

```
.tinted-image {

  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45)
    )

}
```

And nothing happens.

I don't want to use a div, like below. **The thing is that I want to implement it directly in the img tag.**

```
<div class="tinted-div"></div>
.tinted-div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg);
}
```

Please somebody help me? :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tint image using CSS without overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546499/tint-image-using-css-without-overlay)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a similar effect using :after if that helps?

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @abokuro  is that possible without using that overlay div?

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: I don't think it's possible using just CSS. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322548/black-transparent-overlay-on-image-hover-with-only-css

Comment: how can I add this class on image select