# Which CSS3 filter property I should use for which effect

Tags: javascript, css

I have this above image:
[image]

Here you can see 7 controls to implement the effect.

and we know that CSS3 filter property has 13 property according to this: [www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

Now, I can use Contrast, Saturation, Shadow using CSS3 filter property **But** which property I should use for other controls?

Comment: Exposure can be adjusted with brightness. But for tint and warmth, that's probably something you need to apply with a SVG filter on, since there is no CSS filters for those. Highlight and shadows contain algorithmic adjustments to the highly vs lowly exposed areas of the image, and cannot be mimicked using CSS filters. In short, what you're trying to achieve cannot be 100% achieved using CSS alone.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546499/tint-image-using-css-without-overlay)

Comment: @Terry I can use Javascript for that so do you have any resources for that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could try playing with brightness for exposure, it will not be the same result but it is pretty close.

The Shadow will not work as you think, it is a different shadow method. In Instagram or other image manipulation software, shadow and highlight are manipulating the dark and the light colors. Here you need a threshold value of lightness and filter the pixels on the image based on them (other variables might also play role like how close they are to black or white). You will not be able to pull this off purely with CSS however you can do it using JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas.

The same goes for the Warmth. You could kind of try Hue-rotate, or Sepia? but it will not give you the desired effect. Warmth is usually applying a blue filter to get a colder image and a yellow to get a more warm image (in the simplest implemetation). You can also implement this using JavaScript, HTML5 Canvas and CSS is not enough to do this trick.

I am not sure about how the tint effect is implemented but I assume it also cannot be done with pure CSS.

I would suggest looking into Paper.js for solving the above algorithms.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to solve it without any third party library. Only CSS3, JavaScript and HTML5

Comment: You can do that as well but it will be more tedious. You can access the HTML5 Canvas API with Javascript and adjust the values with reading slider values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not have more than 13 filter you must have to create one to apply the filter. The combination of that properties will give you the new filter if want to stay on CSS.

For example:

Using web-kit layout

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale; /*sepia, hue-rotate, invert....*/
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
```

This will give you a tint effect. You can find a lot of these combinations to do your work

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546499/tint-image-using-css-without-overlay)